# What is the language of the Paradise?

Tags: jannah, language

I was wondering what the language of the people is in the paradise (Jannah)? Is that a new language or it is one of the current world languages? As another related question, and actually on the other hand, I wander what the language of the hell (Jahanam) is and "Is it the same, as the language of the Jannah?

*Note: The authentic hadiths (traditions) would be appreciated (as well as the holy Qur'an verses).*

Comment: I think it will be Arabic. I will answer with references as currently I have all the Islamic sites blocked out in the office. Lol.

Comment: Uh-huh, God bless you. I almost reckon so, but not sure. God willing see a referenced answer. Well done mate.

Comment: Did Allah (SWT) speak to Hazrat Musa (AS) in Arabic?

Comment: The Qur'an is explicit that Prophets were sent to their respective nations and spoke in their respective languages. The Qur'an is merely relating past events in Arabic, that's all it is. Hence Allah SWT Communicated in the language Moses AS understood.

Answer (score 11):

Well I couldn't find any authentic hadith about the matter, even if among Muslim people the saying that Arabic would be the language of people in Jannah is well known and a kind of consensus. But there's no sahih hadith or Verse in the Qur'an which clearly supports this opinion.

On the other Hand there are ahadith most of them quoted by Imam at-Tabarni and qualified as weak or fabricated which support this opinion:

> It was narrated by al-Tabaraani in al-Awsat, al-Haakim, al-Bayhaqi in Shu’ab al-Eemaan and others that Ibn ‘Abbaas (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: **“Love the Arabs for three reasons, because I am an Arab, the Qur’aan is Arabic and the speech of the people of Paradise is Arabic.”**

(Qualified as fabricated by ibn al-Jawzi and Imam ad-Dahabi)

> Al-Tabaraani narrated in al-Awsat that Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: **“I am an Arab, and the Qur’aan is Arabic, and the language of the people of Paradise is Arabic.”**

(Qualified as fabricated by al-Albani)

There are similar versions of this last Hadith but as ahadith marfu' (a saying of sahabi or tabi'a) narrated by ibn 'Abbas and Imam az-Zuhari which was quoted in Hadi al arwah of ibn al-Qayyim!

Imam Ibn Kathir pretended in his tafisri of the Verse in surat ash-Shu'ara' ([26:195](http://www.quran.com/26/195))

> in plain Arabic language بلسان عربي مبين

that the language of the day of Qiyamah would be Syrianic and those who enter Jannah will speak Arabic ([Fatwa in Arabic](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/4563))

**Conclusion**

As there doesn't seem to be any clear evidence or reference telling us in which language people will speak neither in Paradise nor Hell nor in the Qiyamah we should accept the conclusion of Imam ibn Taymiyah in his Majmo' al-Fatawa (4/299): *There is no basis for any of these ideas, whether on the grounds of common sense or in any report or text, rather they are mere claims that are devoid of any evidence. And Allaah knows best and is most Wise.* (See this [Fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/83262) for more details)

Comment: What is interesting is that there are also fabricated hadiths by Persians that say the language of Paradise is Persian or so forth! The whole "what is the language of paradise or angels" thing, some scholars suspect, has been a result of Umayyad-Persian rivalries!

Answer (score 1):

I will say that this Hadith can be a true Hadith that Arabic a heaven language. As final revelation of God Al-Quran in Arabic and final prophet Mohammad PBUH is Arab. And as Arabic is just 2500 years old language and transformed from Aramaic the language of Jesus PBUH. Means Arabic replace Aramaic. And as Al- Quran saying that Jesus PBUH will return as a Muslim.

Mohammed PBUH saying that Jesus PBUH will be returning in Syria Damascus which is Arab spoken country means it is a common sense that may be Jesus PBUH speaking Arabic on his PBUH second arrival.

And Mohammed PBUH most famous visit to heaven known as a Mirage in this visit Mohammed PBUH met many Prophets like Jesus PBUH, Moses PBUH and others PBUH and Mohammed PBUH did Imamat to lead in NAMAZ (Pray) to all Prophets, commonsense it all happened in Arabic.

If this is the case then it tell us that Arabic would be heaven language too.

It's a matter of God. Our job as a Muslim/human being is to learn Arabic so we can understand Al- Quran with out depending on others. And possible advantage that we might end up in Paradise with Arabic communication skill in hand.

Abdul Jabbar.

Comment: There's also a Sahih Hadith where the Prophet SAW heard Moses AS praying in his grave. How did the Prophet SAW knew he AS was praying? Surely he SAW knew through the language spoke.

Comment: @Afiq still doesn't prove the point. If Prophet SAW could know that Moses is praying in his grave then surely he would also know the language that Moses used to speak at his time.

Answer (score 0):

) إِنَّ الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَعَمِلُوا الصَّالِحَاتِ يَهْدِيهِمْ رَبُّهُم بِإِيمَانِهِمْ ۖ تَجْرِي مِن تَحْتِهِمُ الْأَنْهَارُ فِي جَنَّاتِ النَّعِيمِ (9) دَعْوَاهُمْ فِيهَا سُبْحَانَكَ اللَّهُمَّ وَتَحِيَّتُهُمْ فِيهَا سَلَامٌ ۚ وَآخِرُ دَعْوَاهُمْ أَنِ الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ (10)
سورة يونس

If the greetings is in Arabic that means language is Arabic too, تحيتهم فيها سلام،
Like hello is for English, and bonjour for french.

Answer (score -3):

It’s True, Arabic is the language if Soul-self n a Devine world is a religion Islam… If you are deaf n blind with dark soul n can't see the spiritual world, that's it you are a trangrsser n a kuffer as well, and far worse than animal...

As you enter paradise, Your Soul-self-light will be greatly programmed with the Arabic language which is now an international and
 Only language of ISLAMIC WORLD and a tongue programmed for your soul... Everything happen as a Devine decree indeed it will be Arabic.

As ALLAH Says to the Prophet PBUH, this day I have perfected your religion (WORLD is perfected with ISLAM, Devine World) as the language Indeed perfected in paradise as well...

Comment: UH-huh, nice answer. I upvote it, but  it can be nicer if you present the related reference as well (to increase the credibility of your nice answer)

Comment: Grammar mistakes need to be corrected. Adding resources would be great.

Answer (score -4):

On my opinion it can be arabic because i have also heard from my parent. Even in our society some muslims moulvi tell people to "learn arabic language because when people enter jannah if they dont know arabic it means it can be big problem for them "what a funny. By naturally you automatically know arabic language in jannah.. By the way Allah knows the best...

Answer (score -4):

Ok Just stop with "IN MY OPINION" .its simple. there is no proof for this as Most scholars have classified this as Fabricated.END OF STORY and Moses(p.b.u.h) also said many things which are mentioned in Quran and Arabic was probably not even a language back then.ALSO hazrat adam's Duaa was SURELY not in Arabic.

Comment: -1, this could be comment, not an individul answer. For example, there are Ahadeeth saying Adam PBUH was talking in Arabic while he and his wife were in Jannah, and that all the prophet were using Arabic in their own prayers. So if you have reference for Adam's Duaa was surely not in Arabic. better for it not to be "your own opinion" :)

Comment: You're wrong. The Qur'an and Sunnah is merely relating past events in Arabic bcuz it's first recipients were Arabs, that's all it is. The Qur'an is explicit that Prophets were sent to their respective nations and spoke in their respective languages.

Answer (score -5):

in my opinion arabic will be the language of heaven but didn't find any exact hadees related to it.