# Tablet or Book?

Tags: quran, verses

I need help responding to the two verses below :

> In a *Tablet*, Guarded. (85:22)

and

> In a *Book* well-guarded, (56:78)

Is the Qur'an inscribed in the Preserved Tablet or Book?

Comment: Cannot the book be written in the tablet? What is the contradiction?

Comment: Tablet or book are only a discription because كتاب in Arabic may refer to a book, a letter, a message or anything that might be written or should be communicated (it even might not be written somewhere physically). Moreover the translation might be consistent as the qur'an once call it Lawh لوح which is a tablet (which make it physical) and once Kitab كتاب. If you shared a link to the verses it would be easier to check the references in these two verses.

Comment: As I have explained [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51188/what-is-the-language-of-the-al-lawh-al-mafooz-the-preserved-tablet/59600#59600) tablet or book are only metaphors for Divine knowledge.